# Failed to return to login page/screen after signing out (Not sure if sign out is successful or not)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm new in flutter and dealing with backend. I faced problem in signing out and I don't know how to fix it due to lack of experience. When I sign out, it would not return to the login screen (Authenticate). I'm not quite sure if the problem lies at the function I wrote at the wrapper or somewhere in auth.
The wrapper widget will be executed everytime the app runs:

```
void main(){
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<User>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: new MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.redAccent,
        ),
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The wrapper code is as below:

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    print(user);

    if (user == null) {
      return Authenticate();
    } else {
      return MyBottomNavigationBar();
    }
  }
}
```

Sign out button function:

```
onPressed: () async {
              await _auth.signOut();
              print('signing out');
            },
```

Auth code:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:mudah_replica/models/user.dart';

class AuthService {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //Create user object based on FirebaseUser
  User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user){
    return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  //Auth change user stream
  Stream<User> get user {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged
        //.map((FirebaseUser user) => _userFromFirebaseUser(user));
        .map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }

  //Sign in anonymously
  Future signInAnon() async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      return user;
    } catch(e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  //Sign in with Email & Password
  Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);

    } catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }


  //Register with Email & Password
  Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);

    } catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  //Sign out
  Future signOut() async {
    try{
      return await _auth.signOut();
    } catch(e){
      print('Fail to sign out');
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: are you navigating from MyBottomNavigationBar to anywhere else ?

Comment: Yes, MyBottomNavigationBar is the root page, also the home page that contains a lot of navigation options to move around the whole app

Answer (score 0):

in your wrapper class, you are returning auth widget instead of navigate to the right screen, so it doesn't route. Instead, you might wanna navigate to the Auth screen. Do something like this:

```
onPressed: () async {
          await _auth.signOut();
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Authenticate())
        },
```

Comment: he is managing state using onAuthStateChanged, so on logout or login there is no need of navigator.